# Where to use cdnAmpURLs?

Tags: accelerated-mobile-page, google-amp

I have the start of an amp site and I am looking to take advantage of Google AMP Cache.  I understand the instructions of generating cdnAmpURLs and I can see that I should use them to prefetch content such as fonts and images but what I don't understand is where to use them for maximum benefit.

Do I:

- Use them on my canonical pages?
- Build a specific sitemap.xml of them?
- Use them in advertising?
- Provide them to external link providers?
- Replace relative path URLs internal to my site with them?

I just don't get that bit, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got there in the end.  I am:

- using the Google AMP Cache URLs in place of relative links in my AMP pages.
- i have updated my canonical rel links to the Google AMP Cache URLs.
- when a user arrives on my non-amp page, I check viewport etc and redirect to AMP if they are a mobile user using the Google AMP Cache URL.
- I am prefetching everything I can aswell.

The key was this section and a few read throughs.  [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview)